# Exclude/remove a string between two special characters using regex

Tags: java, regex, groovy

I was trying to replace/remove any string between `- <branch prefix> /`

Example:

```
String name = Application-2.0.2-bug/TEST-1.0.0.zip
```

expected output :

```
Application-2.0.2-TEST-1.0.0.zip
```

I tried the below regex, but it's not working accurate.

```
String FILENAME = 2.2.1-Application-2.0.2-bug/TEST-1.0.0.zip

println(FILENAME.replaceAll(".+/", ""))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be many ways e.g. you can replace `\w+\/` with a `""`. Note that `\w+` means one or more word characters.

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String FILENAME = "Application-2.0.2-bug/TEST-1.0.0.zip";
        FILENAME = FILENAME.replaceAll("\\w+\\/", "");
        System.out.println(FILENAME);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Application-2.0.2-TEST-1.0.0.zip
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/cqNH7a)